# After adding a delete option, I start to receive a error 500

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

After adding a delete option, I start to receive a error 500 right after i add a new object, not sure why.

I checked if all the tags are closed, they are.
There are no error pointed by eclipse.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div th:each="lembrete : ${lembretes}">
        <form method="post">
            <div class="postIt">
                <input type="text" class="titu" name="nome" th:value="${lembrete.nome}">
                <a class="btn" th:href="${(#mvc.url('EC#deletarLembrete').arg(0, lembrete.id)).build()}">x</a>
                <textarea class="txta" cols="30" name="descr" th:text="${lembrete.descr}"></textarea>
                <button class="btn2" type="submit">salvar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JAVA:**

```
@Controller
public class LembreteController {    

@Autowired
private LembreteRepository lr;

@RequestMapping("/deletarLembrete")
public String deletarLembrete(long id) {
    Lembrete lembrete = lr.findById(id);
    lr.delete(lembrete);

    return "redirect:/eventos";
}
}
```

**Error (the parts I considered important):**

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")

Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "(#mvc.url('EC#deletarLembrete').arg(0, lembrete.id)).build()" (template: "index" - line 27, col 21)

Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "(#mvc.url('EC#deletarLembrete').arg(0, lembrete.id)).build()" (template: "index" - line 27, col 21)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapping not found: EC#deletarLembrete

There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")
```

Comment: The issue isn't syntax, it's the making, as indicated by the error message.

Comment: yah, after i add that <a> with the href and the deletarLembrete method, just stop working and i dont know how to fix it

Comment: From the root cause, Mapping not found: EC#deletarLembrete. Make sure that your RequestMapping is from a Controller

Comment: i eddit to show a little more of the controller class, but yeah, i think it is a controller.